# When is the gcc optimization most effective?

Tags: c, gcc

When I pass the -O3 option to compile C code with gcc, it usually reduces the running time around 10~30% compared to when compiled without optimization. Today I found that one of my program's running time is reduced remarkably, about 1/10, with the -O3 option. Without optimization it took about 7 seconds to complete. However the -O3 option makes in run in 0.7 seconds! I have never seen such incredible amount of time reduction.

So here I wonder what types of program patterns are more likely to benefit from the gcc optimization option, or perhaps are there some ways in programming to have optimization done more feasibly.

The 1/10 code is below. It is a simple program that calculates the sum of all primes numbers less than the macro constant MAXX, by using wheel factorization algorithm.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <time.h>

#define MAXX 5000000
#define PBLEN 92160
#define PBMAX 510510

int main(){
    clock_t startT, endT;
    startT = clock();
    int pArr[7] = {2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17};
    int pBase[PBLEN];
    pBase[0] = 1;
    int i, j, k, index = 1;
    for (i = 19; i <= PBMAX; ++i){
        for (j = 0; j < 7; ++j){
            if (i % pArr[j] == 0){
                goto next1;
            }
        }
        pBase[index] = i;
        ++index;
        next1:;
    }
    uint64_t sum = 2 + 3 + 5 + 7 + 11 + 13 + 17;
    for (i = 1; i < PBLEN; ++i){
        for (j = 0; j < 7; ++j){
            if (pArr[j] <= (int)sqrt((double)pBase[i]) + 1){
                if (pBase[i] % pArr[j] == 0){
                    goto next2;
                }
            }
            else{
                sum += pBase[i];
                goto next2;
            }
        }
        for (j = 1; j < PBLEN; ++j){
            if (pBase[j] <= (int)sqrt((double)pBase[i]) + 1){
                if (pBase[i] % pBase[j] == 0){
                    goto next2;
                }
            }
            else{
                sum += pBase[i];
                goto next2;
            }
        }
        next2:;
    }
    int temp, temp2;
    for (i = PBMAX; ; i += PBMAX){
        for (j = 0; j < PBLEN; ++j){
            temp = i + pBase[j];
            if (temp > MAXX){
                endT = clock();
                printf("%"PRIu64"\n\n", sum);
                printf("%.3f\n", (double)(endT - startT) / (double)CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
                return 0;
            }
            for (k = 0; k < 7; ++k){
                if (temp % pArr[k] == 0){
                    goto next3;
                }
            }
            for (k = 1; k < PBLEN; ++k){
                if (pBase[k] <= (int)sqrt((double)temp) + 1){
                    if (temp % pBase[k] == 0){
                        goto next3;
                    }
                }
                else{
                    sum += temp;
                    break;
                }
            }
            next3:;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: To see what is going on, compile to assembly: `gcc -o O3.s -O3 main.c` and `gcc -o O0.s -O0 main.c`. Then examine and compare the assembly sources (.s files).

Comment: Hyde's correct, but you must use the `-S` option to get assembler output (she probably just forgot it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to guess how this could happen from looking at your code. I'm guessing the thing that takes the longest, by far, is sqrt(). You have tight loops where you're running sqrt() on a value that isn't changing. gcc probably decided to make a single call, save the return, and reuse that. Same results, far less calls to sqrt(), so significantly faster run time. You will probably see the same results manually if you move the calls to sqrt() out of your tight loops and run them less. Run a profiler to be certain though.

So, the short answer - sometimes gcc can fix pretty major issues that you could have fixed yourself, but only if they're small in scope. Usually you need to sit down with a profiler and see what's really taking up your time and how to work around the problem.

Comment: Thanks! You were definitely correct! After I took out the sqrt() into a temporary variable outside the loop, the running time with no optimization is also 0.7 seconds. Now with -O3 it reduces to 0.45 sec. I really should try more not to make so obvious mistakes; also impressed by the smart compiler.